# Do any two coils seperated by some little distance form a transformer?

Tags: transformer

[image]

If I replace the DC source with an AC one, can I say now I have constructed a transformer?

Source of the picture:

https://www.teachoo.com/10742/3114/NCERT-Question-14/category/NCERT-Questions/

Comment: They don't have to be separated, you can have one right on top of the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *If I replace the DC source with an AC one, can I say now I have
> constructed a transformer?*

- A transformer has at least two coupled coils. So does your picture.
- Transformers try to make the coupling as good as possible. Yours will be a single digit percent of coupling (if not less).
- This means that even if both coils were identical, the voltage induced at the secondary would be a tiny percentage of the primary voltage. Not so with a regular transformer.

What you have got is two mutually coupled coils. I guess you can call it a bad transformer if you wanted but, if you did call it a transformer, who is going to mind?

<sub>The whole point about a transformer is that it transforms the impedance on one side to a different impedance on the other side governed by the square of the turns ratio. Yours will be much more convoluted in that respect.</sub>

Comment: With capacitors, it might make a fine resonant transformer. Loose coupling is often desirable for those.